# Asp.net MVC4 | DateFormat

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting issue while passing date from datepicker (in view) to model..

I am using datepicker as given below :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model=> model.ChequeDate,"{0:DD/mm/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control datepicker"})
```

Date picker is already set as **dd/mm/yyyy** format and I am selecting date in that format.

I have defined model as public `System.DateTime ChequeDate { get; set; }` in my model class..

But Date is getting stored in model `ChequeDate` properties as **mm/dd/yyyy format** which is system date format. Its storing Date in model according to system date format.

I have tried adding attributes as

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public System.DateTime ChequeDate { get; set; }
```

**BUT** it does not work

Any idea how to pass date to model in **dd/mm/yyyy** format without changing system date format?

Answer (score 0):

A `DateTime` property gets stored as a `DateTime` in C# regardless of a format. Which is why if you change your system ssettings, the default .ToString() format changes. If you're putting it into a database, or want to display it a certain way, use the Localization stuff (`System.Globalization.CultureInfo`), or `.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")` it. If you dont specify anything, it'll get stored/displayed in the local system date format.

The things you are doing in MVC is for UI - ie, for displaying the date, not for storing it in your database.